# Magento 2 - Add Product Edit link grid action but it shows in the Grid total row

Tags: magento2, grid, action

I add the `product edit` link in `grid action` by using following code

Path of my grid file: `app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Abcreport\Grid.php`

```
$this->addColumn('action', array(
                    'header' => __('Action'),
                    'width' => '100',
                    'type' => 'action',
                    'getter' => 'getProductId',
                    'actions' => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => __('View'),
                            'url' => array('base' => 'catalog/product/edit'),
                            'target'=>'_blank',
                            'field' => 'id'
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter' => false,
                    'sortable' => false,
                    'index' => 'id',
                    'is_system' => true,
                ));
```

The problem is, edit link shows the **grid total row** as well, I need to remove the edit link from **total row**.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

I appreciate, if anybody helps

Comment: what do you mean by "grid total row"? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: ok I will share the screenshot in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your action field, with this one. I added renderer for conditional base edit link

```
        $this->addColumn('action', array(
                'header' => __('Action'),
                'width' => '100',
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getProductId',
                'actions' => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => __('View'),
                        'url' => array('base' => 'catalog/product/edit'),
                        'target'=>'_blank',
                        'field' => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'renderer'  => 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Abcreport\Edit\Tab\Renderer\Abcreportviewaction',
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'id',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));
```

After that, Add renderer file `Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Abcreport\Edit\Tab\Renderer\Abcreportviewaction.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Abcreport\Edit\Tab\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Abcreportviewaction extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{

    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        $productId = $row->getProductId();
        $sku = $row->getSku();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $producturl =  $objectManager->get('\Magento\Backend\Helper\Data')->getUrl('catalog/product/edit',['id' => $productId]);

        if (!empty($productId)){
            return '<a href="'.$producturl.'" target="_blank">View</a>';
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**I hope this will help**